# Нужно скачать все файлы с внешней страницы и собрать в архив

Tags: php, javascript, curl, archive, ziparchive

Нужно написать сценарий, который будет переходить по внешней указанной ссылке и с той страницы, на которую перейдёт скачает все файлы определённого формата, например mp3, на сервер, на сервере соберёт из в архив, который можно будет скачать.
Как это реализовать? Куда копать?

Comment: По сути у вас 2 задачи. Написать парсер который по ссылке будет возвращать список всех загружаемых файлов. И компонент который будет брать список файлов и сохранять их.   Поищите "php http client".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы рассмотрел запуск wget из вашего скрипта.

```
wget -r -A .mp3 URL
```